# su to different user no longer working in 12.04 LTS

Tags: bash, su

I want to log on as tomcat7 user in a different bash command shell. I used to be able to do this by doing the following:

```
sudo su - tomcat7
```

But when I enter this command now I get returned to the shell for the current user. Can someone tell me what the problem might be?

Comment: What login shell is set for user tomcat7? You can check by looking in the /etc/passwd file, or `getent passwd tomcat7`.

Comment: Are you sure your current user is in sudoers group ? I don't understand why you need to go root then tomcat. If you have tomcat7 passwd, try to do only `su - tomcat7` to see if you're switching correctly.

Comment: Yes the user is in the sudoers group. And even if I try it as suggested the problem is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because there is no shell defined in the /etc/passwd file for the tomcat7 user.